# ERR_BAN (-6)on WeChat login response Android

Tags: android, wechat

In WXEntryActvity , `onResp(BaseResp resp)`method we get the response as `-6(ERR_BAN)`.

What is the reason for this response?
Also in Developers account what to give in Application Signature.

```
  @Override
public void onResp(BaseResp resp) {
    Log.d("WEChat", "AuthResp " + resp.errCode);
    switch (resp.errCode) {

        case BaseResp.ErrCode.ERR_OK:
            try {
                SendAuth.Resp sendResp = (SendAuth.Resp) resp;
               // WXEntryActivity.token = sendResp.token;
                Toast.makeText(this, "success "+sendResp.code, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               // sendResp.url;

            } catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Exception while parsing token", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        case BaseResp.ErrCode.ERR_USER_CANCEL:
            Toast.makeText(this, "User canceled the request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case BaseResp.ErrCode.ERR_AUTH_DENIED:
            Toast.makeText(this, "User denied the request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication issue is happening, and due to that wechat login not happening. In We chat console you are giving some keys in wrong way.